# Installing IIS on Win Server 2003 without the installation CD?

Tags: iis, installation, windows-server-2003

The title says most of it.

I have a VM running Windows Server 2003. While setting it up, I didn't install IIS. Now I need it and *the installation ISO I installed from is on another machine that I don't currently have access to*. I know the installation is traditionally done by using add/remove windows components ([msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998483.aspx)), which are prompting me for the CD. Any ideas on how to get around this? Is there a standalone installer anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standalone installer - you will need the files from the installation CD. As GateKiller pointed out, they can be on the network or a drive, but without the Installation CD, you have a problem.

My only suggestion: Try the Trial Version ISO, but that is at your own risk:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb430831.aspx

Answer (score 3):

And when you are prompted for the file location you can point to the equivalent file on another server that already has IIS on it

`\\myotherserver\c$\windows\system32\` and so on

Answer (score 2):

While using add/remove windows components, the dialog should ask you the location of the files which you could enter a location on the local disk or network location.